# MySQL split by time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view which has two columns as below:

```
id    hour_from    hour_to
1     12:00        20:00
2     09:00        13:00
3     07:30        19:00
....................
```

I'm trying to achieve the following with a single query:

```
id    hour
1     12:00        
1     12:30        
1     13:00        
1     13:30       
............
1     19:30        
2     09:00        
2     09:30      
2     10:00       
2     10:30   
............
2     12:30   
............
```

In other words, I want to split each row into multiple rows based on the hour_from and hour_to fields. Was wondering if this is possible or if I have to write a stored procedure to do it.

Comment: what is the criteria for splitting?

Comment: You will need to have a table with times in half-hour increments or sub-query building it on-the-fly, and then `JOIN` your main table to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a rowsource with all the times you want returned. Then you can use a JOIN operation to select the rows to be returned.

If you had a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cal (tm TIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
INSERT INTO cal (tm)  VALUES ('00:00:00'),('00:30:00');
INSERT INTO cal (tm) SELECT ADDTIME(tm,'01:00:00') FROM cal;
INSERT INTO cal (tm) SELECT ADDTIME(tm,'02:00:00') FROM cal;
INSERT INTO cal (tm) SELECT ADDTIME(tm,'04:00:00') FROM cal;
...
```

Then you could use that in your query:

```
SELECT v.id
     , c.tm
  FROM myview v
  JOIN cal c
    ON c.tm >= v.hour_from
   AND c.tm <= v.hour_to
 ORDER BY v.id, c.tm
```

If you want the time values in a specific format, you can use the `DATE_FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT v.id
     , DATE_FORMAT(c.tm,'%H:%i') AS hour_
```

This assumes that the values returned by the view are `TIME` datatype. If they aren't, you'll want to convert them. (Or you could get the same result working with character strings in a canonical format.)

NOTE: It's not mandatory that you have a table; it can be any row source, such as an inline view. You just need enough rows (in your case, assuming half hour increments from 00:00 thru 23:30, thats 48 rows.)

If you have any time ranges that "cross" a midnight boundary (e.g. 22:00 to 02:00), the example query won't return any rows. You'd need to make adjustments.

Something like:

```
 JOIN cal c
   ON ( t.hour_from <= t.hour_to 
      AND c.tm >= v.hour_from
      AND c.tm <= v.hour_to
      )
   OR ( t.hour_from > t.hour_to 
      AND (   c.tm <= v.hour_from
          OR  c.tm >= v.hour_to
          )
      )
```