# Split time intervals into 1 hour intervals mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have checkin  and checkout data at a time stamp level

```
ID    checkin_datetime    checkout_datetime
4     04-01-2019 13:07    04-01-2019 13:09
4     04-01-2019 13:09    04-01-2019 13:12
4     04-01-2019 14:06    04-01-2019 14:07
4     04-01-2019 14:55    04-01-2019 15:06
22    04-01-2019 20:23    04-01-2019 21:32
22    04-01-2019 21:38    04-01-2019 21:42
25    04-01-2019 23:22    04-02-2019 00:23
29    04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15
```

This is output I am looking for where each interval is split into hourly intervals which can be across hours days and so forth, such as:

```
ID       day         HR    Minutes
4     04-01-2019     13    2
4     04-01-2019     13    4
4     04-01-2019     14    1
4     04-01-2019     14    5
4     04-01-2019     14    2
22    04-01-2019     20    27
22    04-01-2019     21    33
25    04-01-2019     23    28
25    04-02-2019     0     23
29    04-02-2019     1     60
29    04-02-2019     2     60
29    04-02-2019     3     60
29    04-02-2019     4     60
29    04-02-2019     5     60
29    04-02-2019     6     15
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using the version 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and just add a new column in your original table to show total duration of each session in minutes.

I think that you might be messing up your data by splitting it at 00:00 on every new day. 
What you are doing this way is basically saying that user with session id 25 has had two sessions, when in reality he/she had one, which started in one day and ended in another.

If this is a requirement, then maybe the original table needs a re-design.

Comment: The Id column here is not a session but the user  login information so with the example of id 25 the person has logged-in into the system across 2 days, and I need to allocate the login times across those into those 2 hours and 2 days for the reporting

Comment: I think I got it.. and I also think I found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257454/split-time-frequency-to-rows/44260448#44260448 which is in TSQL, and one which is in mysql - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103375/mysql-split-by-time-range